# no matching function (constructor) to call to, the candidate differing in being a reference to the given type

Tags: c++, constructor

My compiler complains in a following way:

```
Matrix.cpp:58: error: no matching function for call to ‘List::miterator::miterator(List::miterator)’
List.h:99: note: candidates are: List::miterator::miterator(List::miterator&)
List.h:98: note:                 List::miterator::miterator(List::Node*, Dim)
List.h:97: note:                 List::miterator::miterator(Dim)
```

I have class List and class Matrix that inherits from List. class miterator is placed within class List. The line 58 says :

```
miterator i( nula(ROW) );
```

and is placed inside :

```
Matrix Matrix::operator*( const Matrix& right ) const
```

The matrix is sparse and List is a two dimensional ring. method nula returns iterator on a first marginal sentinel in a given dimension. The dimension is defined globally as :

```
typedef enum { ROW, COL } Dim;
Dim operator!(Dim dim) { return dim == COL ? ROW : COL; }
```

Node of a list is defined within List and contains the following fields :

```
private:
    unsigned index[2];
    T num;
public:
    Node *next[2];
```

I'd appreciate any help, I have no idea what is wrong. Please keep in mind that I'm a beginner C++ programmer. Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
This might be helpful too. From the inside of miterator definition :

```
    miterator( Dim dir ) { direction_flag = dir; }
    miterator( Node *n, Dim dir ) { node = n; memory = n; direction_flag = dir; }
    miterator( miterator &i ) { node = i.node; memory = i.memory; direction_flag = i.direction_flag; }
    ~miterator() {}
    inline bool operator==( const miterator& i) const { return node == i.node; }
    inline bool operator!=( const miterator& i) const { return node != i.node; }
    inline miterator& operator=( const miterator i ) { node = i.node; memory = i.memory; return *this; }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
List::miterator::miterator(List::miterator&)
```

should be

```
List::miterator::miterator(List::miterator const&)
```

A temporary (`nula(ROW)` in your case) can't bind to a non-`const` reference. Either change the constructor (recommended) or don't use a temporary.

```
nula n(ROW);
miterator i(n);
```

Comment: I've completely forgotten about that principle, thank you very much!